# How do I modify the breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I want to modify my bread crumb ( remove one link from bread crumb and add one link to bread drumb).

I tried,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function modulename_system_breadcrumb_alter(\Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
// to get current path and alias 
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $result = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);

// get current route name 
  $route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
// check route is an quickinfo content create in group 
  if ($breadcrumb && $route_name == 'entity.group_content.group_node__quickinfo.create_form') {
// get bread crumb links
    $breadcrumb_links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
// fetch titile of the current path    
    $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle(\Drupal::request(), $route_match->getRouteObject());
    if (!empty($title)) {
// change third link of a breadcrumb 
     $breadcrumb_links['2'] = Link::createFromRoute(t('RZ-schnellinfo'), '<none>');
    }
//    set links again
   $breadcrumb->setLinks($breadcrumb_links);
  }
}
```

SetLinks() ==> work when only bread crumb links doesn't exist, i.e.. we can create new links by using addLinks(). Since we need to remove a link we can use this function .

Then I followed [https://www.drupal.org/node/2026025](http://www.drupal.org/node/2026025)  but I am getting below error.

> exception
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException' with
>   message 'Service                                    [error]
>   'xxxxx.breadcrumb_xxxx_create' for consumer 'breadcrumb' does not
>   implement Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface.' in

Answer (score 1):

As comment said above, you have to implement [`Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Breadcrumb%21BreadcrumbBuilderInterface.php/interface/BreadcrumbBuilderInterface/8.2.x). Here is a working snippet that I use to implement those Breadcrumbs :

It appends a custom routename to all 'Nodes' pages :

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\Your_Module_Namespace\Breadcrumb;

use Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

class Your_Module_NamespaceBreadCrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $attributes) {
    $parameters = $attributes->getParameters()->all();
    // I need my breadcrumbs for a few node types ONLY,
    // so it should be applied on node page ONLY.
    if (isset($parameters['node']) && !empty($parameters['node'])) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));

    $node = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $node_type = $node->bundle();

    // Put the needed logic here

    // addLink example
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('My Page Name', 'drupal_internal.routename'));
    $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route']);

    return $breadcrumb;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above in the start you should use this class .

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;